# Windows authentication and custom roles for a list of users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 web application. I use Windows Authentication. I need to achieve the following:

- create an admin Role
- add specific user to admin Role.
- create a database table to map users to their role to allow the application to check access permissions

The third point is the most important point. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the default Membership and Role Provider please refer to this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) on how creating an intranet application with asp.net mvc 3. But if you want to implement your own membership and role provider i recommend to use this [library](http://codefirstmembership.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Just insert in the web.config the call to the membershipRoleProvider.
than for implementing the roles just call the AddRole, while to check if a user is in a role just call IsUserInRole.
You can find samples and documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx)